# timer task not executing when app is in background

Tags: android, timertask

1)I written timer task to repeat task every 1 sec.but suddenly when I switched to some other app e.g UC browser and come back to my app that timer has stopped..

2)after passing say 50 min timer stopped incrementing

it is happening in my device right now  Motog(2nd gen) but run smoothly on other device I tested on intex,moto turbo,lenovo k3 note..please help to solve this blocker issue...any help is appreciated ..

Comment: http://www.mopri.de/2010/timertask-bad-do-it-the-android-way-use-a-handler/ Use a handler instead of TimerTask, because it runs in the background.

Comment: But even if I keep it in foreground for long time say 50 min it stops incrementing..does same thing handled by handler? @JD9999

Comment: When you say it ran smoothly on your other device, but not your Motog, did the problems above happen on all the other devices as well?

Comment: Yupp after long time but not while switching apps or even if heavy process in background @JD9999

Comment: Its possible that your current device is not powerful enough to run the timer. Try restarting the device and stop any applications that may be using RAM unnecessarily. Your application may just not have enough memory, though I am not sure if there's a way to fix that in Android

Comment: I tried to factory reset  but when messenger app is in background it freezes my app ..but in other app like endomondo timer as it is even if messenger runs in background ..@JD9999

Comment: I didn't say factory reset. What I said was to shutdown your phone and start it up again. And the Handler didn't work for you?

Comment: So far I have not try handler ..as I don't know how handler works @JD9999

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Handler to schedule the task with a specific delay:

```
public class App extends Activity{

    public void onCreate(Bundle bundle){
        super(bundle);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        Handler handle = new Handler();
        handle.postDelayed(getRunnable(), 1000); //1 second = 1000 ms
    }

    public Runnable getRunnable(){
        return new Runnable(){
            public void run(){
                //Do task here
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: actually it is due to service issue i started my service as foreground and now it is working now i m facing http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38282391/timer-task-strange-behaviour?noredirect=1#comment63983429_38282391 this issue @JD9999